# PHP to UDP over a port

Tags: php, sockets, udp, arduino

I need to send data from a web page to an arduino, but without knowing the ip address. My idea is to make the arduino listening on a specific port and the web page would send data to this port. 
Can my idea work ? If yes how to do the php part ? 
Otherwise what can i do ?

Sorry for my english, i'm not really good.

Comment: If you don't know the address you have no chance of sending data successfully. You will need to find it somehow, or code it.

Comment: If the Arduino is on the same subnet, you can send a broadcast to the port.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data to somebody on the Internet you *have* to find out their IP address. There is no other way. If the recipient has a dynamic IP address they need to tell the sender about it somehow. A dynamic DNS service is one example of this.

However if this is all in a local network and you make sure everything is set up correctly, you can also send to a [broadcast address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address). Broadcast packets will be received by any host in the local network.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about PHP, but if you want to do this over a LAN you need to know the hostname. In laymans terms, the hostname acts as the IP address over the LAN.

Comment: A hostname is an IP address? That makes no sense.

Comment: I modified my response. And, sure it does if you're using a LAN with a router that supports DHCP. When your computer turns on, it requests an internal IP address using the DHCP protocol. Part of that request includes the computer's hostname, and the hostname is then saved in the router. When any other computer in the LAN tries to connect to your hostname, the router knows the internal IP address and connects you.

Comment: That depends entirely on how the network is set up. My computers for instance talk directly with my ISP's DHCP servers that do not keep track of hostnames. I'm not sure how common a configuration that trusts hostnames sent via DHCP and keeps track of them in an internal DNS server is.

Comment: Yeah but you could theoretically make a DHCP reservation, and then you don't need to know the IP address directly.

Comment: Yes, that would also be a valid solution on a local network. No need to use something like dynamic DNS if it's not going over the internet.